# CSRF Cookie/Header mismatch - CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I am trying to call a design doc I wrote in CouchDB however when I make the call I get the following error:

```
{"error":"forbidden","reason":"CSRF Cookie/Header mismatch"}
```

I am calling this design doc from an HTML form as a POST. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of CouchDB? afaik, there is no CSRF until v2.0.0 (which is unreleased as of now)

Comment: So, I'm actually using Cloudant... but up until now everything has been exactly the same and a lot more people know CouchDB than Cloudant, so I was asking my questions in terms of CouchDB. I guess this may be the first difference. Do you know if Cloudant has a CSRF, or if so, how I get around this error?

Answer (score 0):

We've disabled this now. It's clearly not possible to pass the CSRF test for a form post with our current implementation. Please confirm you are able to post to Cloudant now, at your convenience.

B.

Comment: I am no longer getting the previous error now, however due to the fact that the HTML form sends post-data that is not in JSON format I am getting the following error:
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}
It is not possible to the set the header in the html form (according to other stackoverflow posts that I have read).. is it possible to do this then?

Comment: Hi, you'll still need to post to couchdb/cloudant endpoints that accept form data. Most only accept json requests by design. docs.couchdb.org and docs.cloudant.com should help you there. From memory, the endpoints that accept form data are /_session, /db (to create/modify docs) and custom Update Handlers you might write yourself.

Comment: Hmmm, okay. I am using a custom Update Handler but it doesn't seem to like it. I'll try looking at the couchdb documentation. I wasn't able to find anything helpful in the cloudant docs.